# Best way to update 1000 items in Shopify?

Tags: php, shopify

I am using the Shopify API and need to update quantities for 1000 items. Of course, I can call the API 1000 times to do the update, but there must be a better way, because the Shopify API is slow and doing an API call a single time for each update will hit API limits, not to mention just being plain inefficient. The Shopify API doesn't support bulk updates for a single API call (passing multiple ids/JSON in a single PUT request), so is there a better / best way to do this?

As a follow-on, I am aware that I could just make one API call per update and stagger them using Delayed Processing to avoid hitting API limits, but that doesn't really address the main issue, which is namely the need to make one API call per update. I am hoping there's some bulk update facility somewhere or some other means to optimize this beyond one-update-per-API, delay-so-you-don't-exceed-PI-limits, lots-of-updates-take-a-LONG-time current approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update 1000 items, you have to make 1000 calls. There are a couple of exceptions to this:

1. Product Variants
2. Product Images

Both of these can be updated in bulk by nesting them under a call to their parent Product.

Comment: Bummer - when you have quite a few products, this imposes a significant load on your servers as well as delays, since we need to batch these API calls so that they don't exceed 500 per 300 seconds.